# Midnight Commander - Quick cd - keyboard shortcut rebind

Tags: mc

How to rebind keyboard shortcuts feature `"Quick cd"` in Midnight Commander? `"Quick cd"` is issued when you press `alt+c` shortcut. When you are in `"Quick cd"` dialog box you can use several other shortcuts for example `History = alt+h, Delete = d, PathAutoCompletition = ESC+tab`. What I want is to rebind the PathAutoCompletition to use only `tab` key as it is in `bash`. In `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` there are lines such as:

```
CdQuick = alt-c
History = alt-h
Delete = delete; d
```

But there is nothing regarding `'SOMETHING-tab'` which is obviously used for path auto competition in `"Quick cd"` dialog. I ahave tried also add several options under `[listbox]` (this is where `'Delete = delete; d'` can be found) but nothing helped. Almost forget to say that I am editing the 100% correct config file since when I tried to change several different values it worked. It seems like this feature is simply missing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Complete =` keyword under the `[input]` section of your `mc.keymap` file

Also check out this excellent [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/532784/midnight-commander-doesnt-use-mc-ini-file) in case your mc uses another keymap file